# Postgresql - Insert into two tables while selecting values from JSON and a table

Tags: json, postgresql, insert

Need some thoughts.

I am trying to insert values into two tables from my nodejs application, I want to insert data into both tables at the same time because I am using first table’s ID as parent ID in 2nd table’s column.
Here is the table structure

Table1

```
                                  Table “public.table1”
   Column    |     Type      | Collation | Nullable |                Default
-------------+---------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------
 id          | integer       |           | not null | nextval(‘table1_id_seq’::regclass)
 name        | text          |           | not null |
 description | character(50) |           |          |
Indexes:
    “table1_pkey” PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Table2:

```
                                  Table “public.table2”
   Column    |     Type      | Collation | Nullable |              Default
-------------+---------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------
 id          | integer       |           | not null | nextval(‘table2_id_seq’::regclass)
 name        | text          |           | not null |
 parent_id   | text          |           | not null |
 sequence    | integer       |           | not null |
 description | character(50) |           |          |
```

I am getting the values from UI as JSON

```
{“table1”:{“name”:“test”,“description”:“test123”,“table2”:[{“column1”:“WMS”,“column2”:“WMS”,“column3”:2,“column4":“rtest”}]}}
```

I have written the below Query but getting below error:

```
WITH new_table1 AS(
  INSERT INTO TABLE1
      (id, name, description)
    VALUES
      (nextval('table_sequence'), 'BDO', 'Sample test') returning id
) INSERT INTO TABLE2(id,parent_id,name,sequence,description)  (  
  nextval('table2_sequence'), 
  (select id from new_table1), 
  (select column1, column3, column4
from jsonb_to_recordset(
    '[{"column1":"WMS","column2":"WMS","column3":2,"column4":"rtest","icon":"sap-icon://it-host"}]'
) r (column1 text, column2 text,column3 int, column4 text, icon text)) );
```

Error:

```
r (column1 text, column2 text,column3 int, column4 text, icon text)) );
ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
LINE 9:   (select column1, column3
      ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the error is that you can only use a scalar expression (subquery that returns a single column) in the `VALUES` list (you missed that keyword too). You can solve this issue like so:

```
WITH new_table1 AS (
  INSERT INTO table1 (name, description)
  VALUES ('BDO', 'Sample test') RETURNING id )
INSERT INTO table2 (parent_id, name, sequence, description)   
  SELECT id, column1, column3, column4
  FROM new_table1,
       jsonb_to_recordset (
         '[{"column1":"WMS","column2":"WMS","column3":2,"column4":"rtest","icon":"sap-icon://it-host"}]'
       ) r (column1 text, column2 text,column3 int, column4 text, icon text);
```

The solution lies in using a query with the `INSERT` statement, rather than a `VALUES` clause. In the query you combine the `INSERT` statement on `table1` with the output from `jsonb_to_recordset()`. This is a Cartesian product, but since the `INSERT` produces just a single row there is no problem.

Note also that I have removed the references to the `id` columns and their sequences - the beauty of default values is that you do not have to specify any when inserting...